# How do I split the movie actors from the OMDB API and then map the results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code so far: https://github.com/justgoof9/IMDB/blob/master/src/App.js

This is the result of the API: [image]

I need help in splitting a part of the API as in title, actors, poster and etc then mapping them.

Comment: please share your code in this question instead of external link. And same applies to images

Comment: I added the image to the question but the code wouldn't look good, it's better with the link.

Comment: You are required to **post your code as text within your question** and not a link to any third party site: [mcve] and never, EVER as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just with the splitting part, I guess you could use the [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method then map the result.

```js
data = {
  'Actors': 'Alice A., Bob B., John J.'
}
let actors = data['Actors']
  .split(',') // split the string
  .map(s => s.trim()) // remove spaces

console.log(actors)
```